# Use template class before it has been specified

Tags: c++, templates

For some reason, I have to return value as an type-specified template class from itself. But the problem is that the template class inherit from a non-template class which have a method returns the value of type-specified template class.

It should be like this one:

```
class Base
{
    // ...
    _Int Foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived
    : public Base
{
public:
    // ...
    _Int Foo() override
    {
        // ...
    }
};

typedef Derived<int> _Int;
```

So my question is: Is there an way that can help me use a specified type of template class before it has been defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To declare a return type of a function, you don't need the definition of the type, only its declaration. Which means you can do this:

```
template <class T>
class Derived;

typedef Derived<int> _Int;

class Base
{
    // ...
    virtual _Int Foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived
    : public Base
{
public:
    // ...
    _Int Foo() override
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61221d3c99417eb3)

---

Two side notes, unrelated to the question:

- Your code was missing `virtual` on the declaration of `Foo`.
- Any name starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved for the C++ implementation (compiler and standard library) and must not be used in user code. You should change the name `_Int` to something else.

  Names which contain two consecutive underscores are similarly reserved, and names which start with an underscore are reserved in global scope.

Comment: These class are in my own namespace. Which naming policy should I take?

Comment: @PENGUINLIONG What's wrong with just `Int`? If it's in a namespace, `_int` would be technically legal as well, but I'd advise against it. I simply don't start my identifiers with underscores.

Answer (score 2):

This is an instance of the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which can be used by taking the derived class as a template parameter to the base class:

```
template<typename Int>
class Base
{
    // ...
    virtual Int Foo() = 0;
};
```

and then passing it explicitly when inheriting:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived
    : public Base<Derived<T>>
{
public:
    // ...
    Derived<T> Foo() override
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd9213efaf4eec44)</kbd>

Comment: OP says that Base is not a template. I would assume he can't change that based on his wording.

Comment: "But the problem is that the template class inherit from a non-template class". He simply says that in this case the base class is not a template. He does not, anywhere, require that to keep it that way. Not to mention that it's very improbable that he cannot change that class, given that it uses `_Int`  which has not been defined anywhere yet.

Comment: Good point. However, I think there is not need to make it a template if he wants to use it with only one type (_Int).

Comment: @rozina If that's the case then `Derived` should not be templated either, and ultimately just use `int` everywhere.